# How to import a very large array Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, ios

I am creating an iOS word game and need to import every word in the English dictionary. I have to check if a string is part of the array or set or whatever it may be. What is the best and most memory efficient way of importing and utilizing the data?

Comment: I think if you are loading every word in the dictionary into memory, you are doing it wrong. Can't you look up words from a database as needed?

Comment: If the words must be stored locally, you should strongly consider using Core Data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I feel like I'm working for them, haha, but [LexiconText](http://lexicontext.com) has a very nice product indeed, and it isn't too hard to determine if the word is in the dictionary or not:

```
Lexicontext *dictionary = [Lexicontext sharedDictionary];
BOOL wordExists = [dictionary containsDefinitionFor:@"MyWord"];
```

<sub>**Note:** I am not affiliated with lexicontext in any way, other than being a happy customer.</sub>

Comment: Whats the memory footprint on this?

Comment: @Ravi quite low. It uses a modification on SQLite in the background, so it only loads in as much as it needs to.

Answer (score 0):

You should use sqlite or another database to store the dictionary. Then you don't have to load it all into memory, but get fast loading of words.

Comment: I'm not sure that SQLite is the best solution there. The data structure isn't table-based in this scenario, but array based. Maybe if the OP was attempting to store other metadata along with a word definition, but SQLite seems too complex. I'd recommend using CoreData instead.

Comment: Yes, using Core Data would be the preferred way to access the data. I meant to say that the OP should redesign how he loads his data so that he is not reading it all from one large file.